# Number of Distinct Lines Passing Through Two Lattice Points

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, coordinate-systems

Consider the point $P(0,2017)$ in the coordinate plane. I want to find the number of distinct lines passing through $P$ that also intersect $y=x^2$ in exactly two lattice points.

Suppose there is a line $L$ that intersects $y=x^2$ in two lattice points $A(a,a^2)$ and $B(b,b^2)$, and passes through $P$. Then, the slope of the line will be $\frac{a^2-2017}{a}$. But it will also be $\frac{b^2-2017}{b}$. Further, the slope will also be $\frac{a^2-b^2}{a-b}$. We can write this as $a+b$ as the $a=b$ case doesn't give us two distinct points. So, $a+b=\frac{a^2-2017}{a}=\frac{b^2-2017}{b}$. From this, we get $a+b=a-\frac{2017}{a}$. This means that $b=-\frac{2017}{a}$. But, we want $b$ to be an integer. Clearly, this happens only when $a=1,-1,2017,-2017$ owing to the primality of $2017$. So we get that $(a,b)=(1,-2017),(-1,2017),(2017,-1),(-2017,1)$. This means that there are exactly two such lines $L$ that satisfy the given conditions.

My questions are- Is my solution correct? If not, where did I go wrong? Is there any faster way to approach this?

Comment: Some steps have alternatives, such as showing and then using the fact that the slope between lattice points on $y=x^2$ is an integer here ($a+b$ is always an integer), but they are not much better than your approach.  It may be worth noting  that you can replace $2017$ with any positive integer and the number of distinct lines will be the number of its positive integer divisors (so $2$ for a prime)

Comment: @Henry, thanks for your input. I wanted a faster approach since this was on a mock test for what many would consider a contest. It's interesting that the number of divisors is the number of lines that satisfy this condition.

Comment: Maybe useful, if you show the slope is an integer, you can use the rational root theorem with $x^2-mx-2017$ (from $y=x^2$ and $y=mx+2017$) to find the roots can only be $\pm 1$ or $\pm 2017$.

Comment: @Merosity, I love this approach. Thanks for it.